# Display frames as animation with python gtk

Tags: python, video, jpeg, pygobject, multimedia

I have a library that collects a frame from a camera and write it to a memory block:

```
buf = 32-byte sequence number + 32-byte data size + JPEG data
```

The frame rate is about 30 frame per second.

I try to show a "live view" of the frames in a python gtk app (python3-gi) with the following code (simplified)

```
...
# Set a GUI callback loop to show the frames.
GLib.timeout_add(FRAME_DURATION_MS,  # timeout interval in ms.
                 updateframeloop,  # callback function to run update periodically.
                 buf)  # frame data block as argument.
...
def updateframeloop(self, buf):
    buf = getifnewframe() # check the sequence number and return jpg data if new frame.
    if buf is not None:
        # tStart = os.times()[-1]
        if self.img is not None:  # self.img is a GtkImage
            _, naturalSize = self.img.get_preferred_size()
            w = naturalSize.width
            h = naturalSize.height

            inputstream = Gio.MemoryInputStream.new_from_bytes(GLib.Bytes(buf))  # convert byte array to stream.
            pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_stream_at_scale(inputstream,  # data src
                                                               w, h,  # img w and h.
                                                               False,  # keep aspect ratio.
                                                               None)  # no cancellable callback.

            self.img.set_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)  # display jpg image. 
            # duration = int((os.times()[-1] - tStart) * 1000)  # duration is about 65ms.
```

Unfortunately, this code only works for low frame rates (FRAME_DURATION_MS >= 100).  But I need to get to 20-25 frames/sec.  At that rate, the time to setup a frame (~ 65ms) is longer the update interval and gtkImage becomes unresponsive (the event queue is probably overwhelmed with messages).  I'm not familiar with multimedia programming, but I would think there should be components better than gtkImage that can handle faster frame rate.  Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found a number of projects using the similar approach and they all break down at a round 10 frames/sec.  So apparently this is the wrong approach.  In the end, I stream the buffer using GStreamer package.  Big learning curve but work nicely.